# Why does twitter opted for red colour for links and hashtag instead of blue?

Tags: hyperlinks

Twitter recently has changed colour the all links and hashtag colour to red instead of blue(previously). With Blue usually the colour used to representing url's and links and red being generally used as the colour for danger/error (ex- password mismatch) - why do you think this change was taken?

Comment: I still see it as blue..

Comment: That colour has been set by the owner of the profile, not Twitter.

Answer (score 3):

It shows up as red for you because you have it set as red in your "**Design**" settings.  Twitter allows you to set your link colour.

[image]

Comment: oops.. my bad - should have checked that. Thanks @JohnGB